# Failed Rotation of Conic

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections, rotations

Given $2x^2+2xy+y^2+\sqrt2x-\sqrt2y$ and $cot2\theta=\frac{A-C}{B}$, I determined $\theta \approx 31.717^{\circ}$

In order to eliminate the $xy$ term, I applied $x=x'cos\theta-y'sin\theta$ and $y=x'sin\theta + y'cos\theta$. Unfortunately, I continually get to a point where the $xy$ terms are not like, resulting in a non-solution.

Any help regarding eliminating the $xy$ term using these formulae would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't pay attention to this robot ; your question is clear. Without being hundred percent sure, I think the discrepancy comes from the fact that the change of coordinates works *backwards*, i.e., you have to turn by $-32.7°$.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: I'm still having no luck. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: $(\frac2{3+\sqrt5})(\frac{(\sqrt5+1)(y-\frac3{\sqrt2})-2(x+\sqrt2)}{\sqrt{(\sqrt5+1)^2+(-2)^2}})^2+(\frac2{3-\sqrt5})(\frac{(\sqrt5-1)(y-\frac3{\sqrt2})+2(x+\sqrt2))}{\sqrt{(\sqrt5-1)^2+2^2}})^2-\frac52=0$ simplifies to your equation. From this we read the center $(-\sqrt2,\frac3{\sqrt2})$ and the semi-major axis $a=\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{3-\sqrt5}}\approx 2.56$ and semi-minor axis $b=\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}}\approx 0.98$ of the ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we compute $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ from the cotangent relationship.  Let $\theta = \frac{1}{2} \cot^{-1} \frac{1}{2}$.  Then by considering a right triangle with adjacent leg $1$, opposite leg $2$, and hypotenuse $\sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}$, we see that $$\cos \cot^{-1} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}. \tag{1}$$  Hence by the half-angle identity,
$$\cos \theta = \cos \frac{1}{2} \cot^{-1} \frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{ \frac{1 + \cos 2\theta}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + 1/\sqrt{5}}{2}}, \quad \sin \theta = \sqrt{ \frac{1 - 1/\sqrt{5}}{2} }.  \tag{2}$$  Since $\theta$ is in quadrant I, both of the signs for $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ in $(2)$ will be positive.

Next, we easily compute $$2 \sin \theta \cos \theta = \sin 2\theta = \sin \cot^{-1} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}. \tag{3}$$

So for the transformation $$(x,y) = (x' \cos \theta - y' \sin \theta, x' \sin \theta + y' \cos \theta), \tag{4}$$ we find
$$\begin{align}
x^2 &= x'^2 \cos^2 \theta - 2x'y' \cos \theta \sin \theta + y'^2 \sin^2 \theta \\
&= \frac{1 + 1/\sqrt{5}}{2} x'^2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} x'y' + \frac{1 - 1/\sqrt{5}}{2} y'^2, \tag{5} \\
xy &= (x'^2 - y'^2) \cos \theta \sin \theta + x'y' (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta) \\
&= (x'^2 - y'^2) \frac{1}{2} \sin 2\theta + x'y' \cos 2\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} (x'^2 + x'y' - y'^2), \tag{6} \\
y^2 &= x'^2 \sin^2 \theta + 2x'y' \cos \theta \sin \theta + y'^2 \cos^2 \theta \\
&= \frac{1 - 1/\sqrt{5}}{2} x'^2 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} x'y' + \frac{1 + 1/\sqrt{5}}{2} y'^2. \tag{7}
\end{align}$$

Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
2x^2 + 2xy + y^2
&= \left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1 - 1/\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) x'^2 + \left(-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right) x'y' \\
&\quad + \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1 + 1/\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)y'^2 \\
&= \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} x'^2 + \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}y'^2. \tag{8}
\end{align}$$

The linear terms $\sqrt{2} x - \sqrt{2} y$ under the transformation $(4)$ do not contribute any $xy$ terms.